# data preprocessing: missing labels

Tags: dataset, data, preprocessing

I have a classification task to predict {0,1} labels, but in my dataset I  only have data with 1 labels. Class indicates that the buyer has made a purchase of some product.

Features: user id, product id, and time of purchases.

User ID: numeric from 0 to 20.000,

Product ID: numeric from 0 to 881

How to solve this kind of tasks? I should use some 0-data generation, or there is some method, which can predict correctly without 0-data? Thanks.

Comment: Kindly post a sample of your data which will help us in better understanding the question.

Comment: First of all, you need to understand what each class represents. Normally, a dataset like that is not suitable for building a machine learning model, since your model will be trained only with 1 class. I agree with @spectre, we need more information about the data.

Comment: is there a time dependency between the samples in your dataset?

Comment: @spectre updated

Comment: @KonstantinosSkoularikis updated

Comment: @KhanisRok yes, also there is column of timestamps

Answer (score 1):

This task could be treated as a [one-class classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-class_classification) problem, where a binary classifier is trained only with positive instances. Instead of determining the optimal limit between classes, the model tries to determine what characterizes the positive class, considering everything else as negative.

Comment: thanks. can you recommend good models for this task in addition to those described in the article?

Comment: @anorexy [one-class SVM](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.OneClassSVM.html) is the most standard method.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly
You have data like this

| UserId | ProductId | Timestamp | Label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Sugar | 21-08-03 | 1 |
| B | Carrots | 21-08-02 | 1 |
| A | Carrots | 21-08-02 | 1 |
| C | Pinaple | 21-08-01 | 1 |
| A | Sugar | 21-08-01 | 1 |

So in fact **you actually have many 0 labels**, more than 1 labels, which are all the products a client didn't buy

If you want to **predict the next product a client will purcharse**, you could make a time series for each user where **the products are the labels**. You could output a binary vector of 881 dimensions.

Each dimension corresponds to a product id and the value is 1 if the user bought the product that day, 0 otherwise

Then a trained model would try to predict which products a client will purcharse each day

If the task is to **make product recommendations for a client**
one way would be to make a matrix-factorization model

You would need a User x Product score, one way to do that is to get the proportion of purcharses a User buy a Product

You could use this to build a matrix Num_Users x Num_Products

| User\Product | Sugar | Carrots | Pinaple |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0.6 | 0.3 |  |
| B |  | 1 |  |
| C |  |  | 1 |

The algorithm would fill the blanks and predict a "score" for each product to each user

| User\Product | Sugar | Carrots | Pinaple |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0.6 | 0.3 | 0.01 |
| B | 0.2 | 1 | 0.1 |
| C | 0 | 0.1 | 1 |

Then you could set a threshold to define when a client would like this or not